# Swift - How to set NSNull when values in dictionary are nil

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a dictionary:

```
var formSearchValues : Dictionary<String, Any?> = [:]
```

And I have a function:

```
func searchProvider(lastName: String, firstName : String, company : String){
....
}
```

The dictionary has the following keys:

```
formSearchValues["lastname"]
formSearchValues["firstname"]
formSearchValues["company"]
```

I need to pass to `searchProvider` function each string but if any of the values `= nil` then have to pass `NSNull()` instead.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

If the optionalValue does not equal nil, use the optionalValue as Any, if it does equal nil use NSNull() as Any. Happy coding!

`formSearchValues["lastname"] = optionalValue != nil ? optionalValue as Any : NSNull() as Any`

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this :

```
func searchProvider(lastName: String?, firstName : String?, company : String?){
....
}
```

The interrogation mark will make your variables as optional so when you call the searchProvider method you will be allow to pass nil in your parameters.